# How to hide a keyboard in iOS v.10 in ipad using appium automation in java?

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I have tried using driver.hideKeyboard() and I have even used keyboard strategies with no success. The layout in the keyboard shows the hide keyboard icon and that has to be pressed for hiding the keyboard.

Comment: Try to tap/swipe down outside the keyboard area , this will hide the keyboard and also it depends upon the app. IT MAY WORK ...  driver.hideKeyboard() works only for Android

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that too, but that isn't working. I have even tried sending RETURN through presskey(). Even that didn't work.

Comment: driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); Try this.

Comment: I have tried that too, it isn't working.

Comment: could you provide the code snippet which is used on that page?